# GROUP BY UPPER(XXX) with Criteria in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, group-by

I'm trying to modify my Hibernate criteria query to add something like `GROUP BY UPPER (PERSONID)`. I've searched a lot but I have not find anything about this.

The code I want to change is:

```
Projections.groupProperty("PersonId");
```

I have not find an ignore-case method or an upper method to Projections object..I'm a bit desperate.

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a native query and execute raw SQL.

Use `entityManager.createNativeQuery()`

Often it's just simpler and faster to go direct than figure out how to do it "properly" via HQL.

Comment: OK, so there is no equivalent in hibernate to GROUP BY UPPER(X)? I will use the SQL query. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Projections#sqlGroupProjection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html).

```
Projections.sqlGroupProjection("upper({alias}.PERSONID) as pid",
                    "PERSONID",
                    new String[] { "pid" },
                    new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.STRING })
```

Dont forget {alias} and to use column name from table.